# can't blend link with background div color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to put a link inside a colored div, but it makes this weird empty box in the div where the text for the link is. How can i solve this problem?
Here is a link to the picture because it won't let me post a picture until i get more reputation. Sorry...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW3o7.jpg
here is my css code..

```
#second_page {
height:100px;
width:200px;
border-radius:5px;
background-color: blue;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

So if you could point out what i did wrong and how to fix it, i would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: can't repeat your result, it just works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably somewhere else in you css you set the background color of a to green. When I create a div with this styles and add a link to it it works fine.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works just fine, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umET7/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="second_page">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#second_page {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
a {
    color: #fff;
}
```